# How to specify a placeholder for things like user-defined types in yacc?

Tags: parsing, yacc

When using yacc, we specify patterns like

`type : builtInType
     | userDefinedType`

`builtInType` is quite easy, because we can just list them all; but `userDefinedType` is a dynamic part, what's in this set is determined by what types are defined before in the source file.

How can I specify the pattern for `userDefinedType`?

Answer (score 1):

For something like that you would simply use the *identifier* token for `userDefinedType`. It is not known in advance which identifiers refer to user-defined types and which do not, so you have few other options.

The determination as to what type is being referenced and whether it is legal in context is often deferred to the semantic analysis phase.